# Visual studio, build failed with no errors

Tags: visual-studio, build

I have a project in visual studio 2013 that worked well.
At the last rebuild (with no changes) it failed and I didn't got errors.
I tried to restart everything and even build a new project with no luck. I reinstalled my VS2013 and nothing... :(

when I changed the build log to diagnostic, I got the follow result :

```
5f7f11d50a3a".
          Resolved file path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Deployment.dll".
          Reference found at search path location "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
              For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
              Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Deployment.winmd", but it didn't exist.
          This reference is not "CopyLocal" because it's a prerequisite file.
          The ImageRuntimeVersion for this reference is "v4.0.30319".
      Primary reference "System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
          Resolved file path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Drawing.dll".
          Reference found at search path location "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
              For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
              Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Drawing.winmd", but it didn't exist.
          This reference is not "CopyLocal" because it's a prerequisite file.
          The ImageRuntimeVersion for this reference is "v4.0.30319".
      Primary reference "System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
          Resolved file path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Management.dll".
          Reference found at search path location "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
              For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
              Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Management.winmd", but it didn't exist.
          This reference is not "CopyLocal" because it's a prerequisite file.
          The ImageRuntimeVersion for this reference is "v4.0.30319".
      Primary reference "System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".
          Resolved file path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Windows.Forms.dll".
          Reference found at search path location "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
              For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
              Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Windows.Forms.winmd", but it didn't exist.
          This reference is not "CopyLocal" because it's a prerequisite file.
          The ImageRuntimeVersion for this reference is "v4.0.30319".
      Primary reference "System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".
          Resolved file path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xml.dll".
          Reference found at search path location "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
              For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
              Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xml.winmd", but it didn't exist.
          This reference is not "CopyLocal" because it's a prerequisite file.
          The ImageRuntimeVersion for this reference is "v4.0.30319".
      Primary reference "System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".
          Resolved file path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll".
          Reference found at search path location "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
              For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
              Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xml.Linq.winmd", but it didn't exist.
          This reference is not "CopyLocal" because it's a prerequisite file.
          The ImageRuntimeVersion for this reference is "v4.0.30319".
      Primary reference "System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".
          Resolved file path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll".
          Reference found at search path location "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
              For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
              Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.winmd", but it didn't exist.
          This reference is not "CopyLocal" because it's a prerequisite file.
          The ImageRuntimeVersion for this reference is "v4.0.30319".
      Primary reference "System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".
          Resolved file path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Core.dll".
          Reference found at search path location "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
              For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
              Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Core.winmd", but it didn't exist.
          This reference is not "CopyLocal" because it's a prerequisite file.
          The ImageRuntimeVersion for this reference is "v4.0.30319".
      AssemblyFoldersEx location: "{Registry:Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework,v4.0,AssemblyFoldersEx}"
              C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Workflow Manager\1.0\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft WCF Data Services\5.6\bin\.NETFramework\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft WCF Data Services\5.0\bin\.NETFramework\
              C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\VSTO40\v4.0.Framework\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office15\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Common\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SharePoint\PublicAssemblies\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\VBPowerPacks\v10.0\
              C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\TEMPLATE\WorkflowActivities\

              C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\WorkflowActivities\
              C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\
              C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\RIA Services\v1.0\Libraries\Server\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Open XML SDK\V2.5\lib
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETFramework\v4.0\4.3.0.0\Type Providers\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETFramework\v4.0\4.3.0.0\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETFramework\v4.0\4.3.1.0\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\3.0\Runtime\v4.0\Type Providers\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\3.0\Runtime\v4.0\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.0\Prototyping\Libraries\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.0\Libraries\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v2.0\Assemblies\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\

              C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Microsoft Identity Extensions\1.0\
              C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7DEBUG\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\VSTA30\v11.0\.NET2.0\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SharePoint\PublicAssemblies\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\VBPowerPacks\v10.0\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\PublicAssemblies\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Chart Controls\Assemblies
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETFramework\v2.0\2.3.0.0\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Blend\
              C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Blend\
    Done executing task "ResolveAssemblyReference".
    Done building target "ResolveAssemblyReferences" in project "TomaMix_Grades.vbproj".
    Target "GenerateBindingRedirects" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(AutoGenerateBindingRedirects)' == 'true' and '$(GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType)' == 'true') was evaluated as ('' == 'true' and 'true' == 'true').
    Target "GenerateBindingRedirectsUpdateAppConfig" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(AutoGenerateBindingRedirects)' == 'true' and '$(GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType)' == 'true' and Exists('$(_GenerateBindingRedirectsIntermediateAppConfig)')) was evaluated as ('' == 'true' and 'true' == 'true' and Exists('obj\x86\Debug\TomaMix_Grades.vbproj.TomaMix Grades.exe.config')).
    Target "PrepareForBuild" skipped. Previously built successfully.
    Target "ResolveKeySource" skipped, due to false condition; ($(SignManifests) == 'true' or $(SignAssembly) == 'true') was evaluated as (false == 'true' or  == 'true').
    Target "ResolveAssemblyReferences" skipped. Previously built successfully.
    Target "ResolveComReferences" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "C:\Development\TomaMix\TomaMix\TomaMix_Grades\TomaMix_Grades\TomaMix_Grades.vbproj" (target "ResolveReferences" depends on it):
    Task "MakeDir"
    Done executing task "MakeDir".
    Task "ResolveComReference"
      Using cache file at "obj\x86\Debug\TomaMix_Grades.vbproj.ResolveComReference.cache".
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2234,5): warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "e64169b3-3592-47d2-816e-602c5c13f328" version 1.1. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2234,5): warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "7b92f833-027d-402b-bff9-a67697366f4e" version 1.0. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2234,5): warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "6bf52a50-394a-11d3-b153-00c04f79faa6" version 1.0. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2234,5): warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "7b92f833-027d-402b-bff9-a67697366f4e" version 1.0. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2234,5): warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "29866aed-1e14-417d-ba0f-1a2be6f5a19e" version 1.0. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2234,5): warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "6bf52a50-394a-11d3-b153-00c04f79faa6" version 1.0. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))
      COM Reference 'MSComctlLib' is the interop assembly for ActiveX control 'AxMSComctlLib' but was marked to be linked by the compiler with the /link flag. This COM reference will be treated as a reference and will not be linked.
      Resolving COM reference for item "ADODB" with a wrapper "primary".
      Determining dependencies of the COM reference "ADODB".
      Resolving COM reference for item "stdole" with a wrapper "primary".
      Determining dependencies of the COM reference "stdole".
      Resolved COM reference for item "stdole": "C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\stdole\7.0.3300.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\stdole.dll".
      Resolved COM reference for item "ADODB": "C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\ADODB\7.0.3300.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\ADODB.dll".
      Resolving COM reference for item "Microsoft.Office.Core" with a wrapper "primary".
      Determining dependencies of the COM reference "Microsoft.Office.Core".
      Resolved COM reference for item "Microsoft.Office.Core": "C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Office\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Office.dll".
      Resolving COM reference for item "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access" with a wrapper "primary".
      Determining dependencies of the COM reference "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access".
      Resolving COM reference for item "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao" with a wrapper "primary".
      Determining dependencies of the COM reference "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao".
      Resolved COM reference for item "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao": "C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.dll".
      Resolving COM reference for item "VBIDE" with a wrapper "primary".
      Determining dependencies of the COM reference "VBIDE".
      Resolved COM reference for item "VBIDE": "C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Vbe.Interop\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.dll".
      Resolving COM reference dependency "2a75196c-d9eb-4129-b803-931327f72d5c" version 2.8.
      Resolved COM reference dependency "2a75196c-d9eb-4129-b803-931327f72d5c" version 2.8: "C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\ADODB\7.0.3300.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\ADODB.dll"
      Resolved COM reference for item "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access": "C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.dll".
      Resolving COM reference for item "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word" with a wrapper "primary".
      Determining dependencies of the COM reference "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word".
      Resolved COM reference for item "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word": "C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll".
      Resolving COM reference for item "MSComctlLib" with a wrapper "primary".
      Determining dependencies of the COM reference "MSComctlLib".
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2234,5): warning MSB3283: Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "MSComctlLib". Verify that (1) the COM component is registered correctly and (2) your target platform is the same as the bitness of the COM component. For example, if the COM component is 32-bit, your target platform must not be 64-bit.
      Resolving COM reference for item "JRO" with a wrapper "tlbimp".
      Determining dependencies of the COM reference "JRO".
      Resolving COM reference dependency "2a75196c-d9eb-4129-b803-931327f72d5c" version 2.8.
      Resolved COM reference dependency "2a75196c-d9eb-4129-b803-931327f72d5c" version 2.8: "C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\ADODB\7.0.3300.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\ADODB.dll"
      Processing COM reference "JRO" from path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msjro.dll". Type 'ReplicaTypeEnum' imported.
      Processing COM reference "JRO" from path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msjro.dll". Type 'VisibilityEnum' imported.
      Processing COM reference "JRO" from path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msjro.dll". Type 'UpdatabilityEnum' imported.
      Processing COM reference "JRO" from path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msjro.dll". Type 'SyncTypeEnum' imported.
      Processing COM reference "JRO" from path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msjro.dll". Type 'SyncModeEnum' imported.
      Processing COM reference "JRO" from path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msjro.dll". Type 'FilterTypeEnum' imported.
      Resolved COM reference dependency "2a75196c-d9eb-4129-b803-931327f72d5c" version 2.8: "C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\ADODB\7.0.3300.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\ADODB.dll"
      Processing COM reference "JRO" from path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msjro.dll". Type 'IReplica' imported.
      Processing COM reference "JRO" from path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msjro.dll". Type 'Filters' imported.
      Processing COM reference "JRO" from path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msjro.dll". Type 'Filter' imported.
      Processing COM reference "JRO" from path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msjro.dll". Type 'IJetEngine' imported.
      Processing COM reference "JRO" from path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msjro.dll". Type 'Replica' imported.
      Processing COM reference "JRO" from path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msjro.dll". Type 'JetEngine' imported.
      Resolved COM reference for item "JRO": "obj\x86\Debug\Interop.JRO.dll".
      Resolving COM reference for item "Scripting" with a wrapper "tlbimp".
      Determining dependencies of the COM reference "Scripting".
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type 'CompareMethod' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type 'IOMode' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type 'Tristate' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type 'FileAttribute' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type '__MIDL___MIDL_itf_scrrun_0000_0000_0001' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type 'IDictionary' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type 'Dictionary' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type 'IFileSystem' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type 'IDriveCollection' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type 'IDrive' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type 'DriveTypeConst' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type '__MIDL___MIDL_itf_scrrun_0001_0001_0001' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type 'IFolder' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type 'IFolderCollection' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type 'IFileCollection' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type 'IFile' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type 'ITextStream' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type 'SpecialFolderConst' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type '__MIDL___MIDL_itf_scrrun_0001_0001_0002' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type 'IFileSystem3' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type 'StandardStreamTypes' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type '__MIDL___MIDL_itf_scrrun_0001_0001_0003' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type 'FileSystemObject' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type 'Drive' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type 'Drives' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type 'Folder' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type 'Folders' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type 'File' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type 'Files' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type 'TextStream' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type 'IScriptEncoder' imported.
      Processing COM reference "Scripting" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll". Type 'Encoder' imported.
      Resolved COM reference for item "Scripting": "obj\x86\Debug\Interop.Scripting.dll".
      Resolving COM reference for item "AxMSComctlLib" with a wrapper "aximp".
      Determining dependencies of the COM reference "AxMSComctlLib".
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\AxImp.exe C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSCOMCTL.OCX /out:obj\x86\Debug\AxInterop.MSComctlLib.dll 
      Generated Assembly: C:\Development\TomaMix\TomaMix\TomaMix_Grades\TomaMix_Grades\obj\x86\Debug\MSComctlLib.dll
      Generated Assembly: C:\Development\TomaMix\TomaMix\TomaMix_Grades\TomaMix_Grades\obj\x86\Debug\AxInterop.MSComctlLib.dll
      Resolved COM reference for item "AxMSComctlLib": "obj\x86\Debug\AxInterop.MSComctlLib.dll".
    Done executing task "ResolveComReference" -- FAILED.
    Done building target "ResolveComReferences" in project "TomaMix_Grades.vbproj" -- FAILED.
    Target "_CheckForCompileOutputs" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "C:\Development\TomaMix\TomaMix\TomaMix_Grades\TomaMix_Grades\TomaMix_Grades.vbproj" (target "_CleanGetCurrentAndPriorFileWrites" depends on it):
    Done building target "_CheckForCompileOutputs" in project "TomaMix_Grades.vbproj".
    Target "_SGenCheckForOutputs" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(_SGenGenerateSerializationAssembliesConfig)' == 'On' or ('@(WebReferenceUrl)'!='' and '$(_SGenGenerateSerializationAssembliesConfig)' == 'Auto')) was evaluated as ('Off' == 'On' or (''!='' and 'Off' == 'Auto')).
    Target "_CleanGetCurrentAndPriorFileWrites" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "C:\Development\TomaMix\TomaMix\TomaMix_Grades\TomaMix_Grades\TomaMix_Grades.vbproj" (target "_CleanRecordFileWrites" depends on it):
    Task "ReadLinesFromFile"
    Done executing task "ReadLinesFromFile".
    Task "ConvertToAbsolutePath"
    Done executing task "ConvertToAbsolutePath".
    Task "FindUnderPath"
      Comparison path is "C:\Development\TomaMix\TomaMix\TomaMix_Grades\TomaMix_Grades".
    Done executing task "FindUnderPath".
    Task "FindUnderPath"
      Comparison path is "bin\x86\Debug\".
    Done executing task "FindUnderPath".
    Task "FindUnderPath"
      Comparison path is "obj\x86\Debug\".
    Done executing task "FindUnderPath".
    Task "RemoveDuplicates"
    Done executing task "RemoveDuplicates".
    Done building target "_CleanGetCurrentAndPriorFileWrites" in project "TomaMix_Grades.vbproj".
    Target "_CleanRecordFileWrites" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "C:\Development\TomaMix\TomaMix\TomaMix_Grades\TomaMix_Grades\TomaMix_Grades.vbproj" (target "CoreBuild" depends on it):
    Task "RemoveDuplicates"
    Done executing task "RemoveDuplicates".
    Task "MakeDir"
    Done executing task "MakeDir".
    Task "WriteLinesToFile"
    Done executing task "WriteLinesToFile".
    Done building target "_CleanRecordFileWrites" in project "TomaMix_Grades.vbproj"
    Build FAILED.
    Time Elapsed 00:00:02.65
    ========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4s91eIhxfHGRUlJNmd2alBScmM/view?usp=sharing][the link for the full log]

In the end it says that the build failed.

The interesting issue is when I tried to rebuild it on VS12, the same problem, however when I rebuild it on other machine (copied the same project folder to other computer) it worked !!!

please any suggestions ? I don't want to reinstall my OS...

Thanks for your help, Roy

Comment: Has your project's filenames or path changed? I had a similar issue with that.

Comment: The log also suggests that your .net framework is missing. Check that your framework is where it's supposed to be.

Comment: No, nothing changed. :( Like I said, in other computer it works...

Comment: The machine is not fit to build this project, it is missing a bunch of required components.  It is complaining about Adobe Acrobat, Apple QuickTime and Windows Media Player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a build works on one machine, but not another using the same exact copied folder, and the build failure is due to the location of .dll's as it is in this instance; Most likely (almost all scenarios I've resolved) the issue lies in the location of those assemblies.

Likely candidates:

1. You have various frameworks installed in a different location and are possibly using non relative pathing.
2. Bit issues between the installed frameworks and the code, which may be your case as indicated by the error here:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2234,5): warning MSB3283: Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "MSComctlLib". Verify that (1) the COM component is registered correctly and (2) your target platform is the same as the bitness of the COM component. For example, if the COM component is 32-bit, your target platform must not be 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the issue appeared after an upgrade to windows 10. My project is in Visual Studio 2013 using framework 4.5. I can't guarantee that it was not my doing or some act of the upgrade but my project had references (both were listed in  -> References) to ADODB and MSDATASRC. I checked my project if there was actually any code referencing anything from those components but could not find anything so I simply removed those references and the issue went away.

Answer (score 1):

My VB.NET project had also ADODB reference. After windows 10 upgrade the error started.
I simply removed and added the references again and found that a line replaced by three lines as below:

```
<WrapperTool>primary</WrapperTool>
```

replaced by

```
<WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
<Isolated>False</Isolated>
<EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mine was resolved by removing the reference to "Microsoft HTML Object Library" and adding it again in the project. The changes in project file on re-add were same as pointed out by Muhammad Arshad Awan.